# java NoSuchElementException: no line found

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

edit:
adding the one of the methods called below, just in case the problem is with the method, not the loop.

Below is a switch menu, there are several cases in the switch. Each case calls a a public void method form another class, and completes successfully, is supposed to displays the menu method (method that prints menu options) and allow the user to select another option. Currently, after completing one case, the program showMenu() again, then breaks at instantly:

```
String menu = in.nextLine();
```

on the second iteration of the menu and sends back

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
```

Question: I need the program to pause or something similar after showMenu(); to let the user input a menu selection, currently the menu displays and the program crashes instantly

Cheers

```
public class Menu {
    public static char selection;
    public static String quitting = "you dun son";
    public static String errorMessage = "THAAAAATSS A menu WRRRAAAAAPPP";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        do {
            showMenu();
            String menu = in.nextLine();
            if (menu.length() > 0) {
                selection = menu.toLowerCase().charAt(0); // extract the first char of the line read
            } else {
                selection = '\0';
                System.out.println("invalid input:\t" + selection);
                System.out.println("Press enter to continue...");
            }
            switch (selection) {
                case 'f':
                    FuelConsole fuelObject = new FuelConsole();
                    fuelObject.fuelCalc();
                    break;
                case 'g':
                    GameConsole gameObject = new GameConsole();
                    gameObject.gameCalc();
                    break;
                case 'q':
                    System.out.println("\nEnding Now\n");
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Instruction is invalid");
                }
        } while (selection != 'Q' && selection != 'q');
        {
            System.out.println(quitting);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

a test method:

```
public class FuelConsole {

    public static String errorMessage = "THAAAAATSS A fuel calc WRRRRAAAAAPPPPPPPPPPPP";
    public static Double acceptableCentsPerLitre = 16.00;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void fuelCalc() {

    try {
        System.out.println("\nyou selected option 'f' --- here you will enter some information and find average fuel for ONE trip. ");
        System.out.println("please enter the amount of fuel in litres:\n ");
        float fuel = scan.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("please enter the price of fuel in cents (not dollars and cents, only CENTS (lulz)):\n ");
        int cent = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("please enter the number of kilometers travelled on the tank:\n ");
        float kilo = scan.nextFloat();

        float returnAFC = afc(fuel, kilo);
        float returnAC = ac(returnAFC, cent);

        System.out.println("average consumption: \t" + returnAFC);
        System.out.println("average cost: \t\t" + returnAC);
        if (returnAC > acceptableCentsPerLitre) {
            System.out.println("Average fuel is above 16c per litre");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Average fuel is below 16c per litre");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(errorMessage);
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        scan.close();
    }

}

public static float afc(float x, float z) {
    float result = x / z;
    return result;
}

public static float ac(float x, int y) {
    float result = x * y;
    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: Works fine for me, what input are you giving?

Comment: user is asked to submit a specific word, each word has a different first character, which is used for input. .charAt(0); cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you create a new Scanner in the `FuelConsole` Class.
And you also close it in the finally block.

But when you call close() on scanner it also closes the underlaying InputStream too. (`System.in` in this case) And because your top-level Scanner uses the same InputStream, it cannot catch any more input from it.

The solution could be if you pass the top level scanner as an argument to other objects:

```
            case 'f':
                FuelConsole fuelObject = new FuelConsole();
                fuelObject.fuelCalc(in);
                break;
            case 'g':
                GameConsole gameObject = new GameConsole();
                gameObject.gameCalc(in);
                break;
```

and

```
public void fuelCalc(Scanner scan) {

try {

...
```

and delete the `finally` block